# @PropertySource cannot find classpath:

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [request-
ws/src/main/resources/application.yml] cannot be opened because it does 
not exist
```

Class with the issue:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:request-ws/src/main/resources/application.yml")
public class RequestDataSource {
```

Now I am trying to access the `yml` file in from a different module. The module name is `request-ws`. The goal to to create two data sources. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with the word - module? Is request-ws dependency?

Comment: check this "classpath*:application.yml"

Comment: @VladoDemcak I am using intellij, a module in a sense is like a project and a package. "Modules contain everything that is required for their specific tasks: source code, build scripts, unit tests, deployment descriptors, and documentation. However, modules exist and are functional only in the context of a project. Configuration information for a module is stored in a .iml module file."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my project is broken down into modules when the war file is made my `application.yml` file ends up in `WEB-INF` Put this on on your class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:WEB-INF/classes/application.yml")
public class DataSourceConfig {
```

Answer (score 0):

The classpath for `application.yml` should be under: `src/main/resources`

according to: `classpath:request-ws/src/main/resources/application.yml`

you obviously don't have that yml file under:

`src/main/resources/request-ws/src/main/resources/application.yml`

Try to create your custom folder under: `src/main/resources`

Comment: This project is broken down into modules. Each module is linked to each other via gradle. In the module with the main method is the is where the yml file is located `src/main/recources/application.yml`